# El botón de iniciar aplicación de swing en eclipse no aparece

Tags: java, java-swing

Puede parecer un poco tonto, pero estoy haciendo una calculadora para swing y el tema es que no me sale el botón de ejecutar, solo me sale el de run last tool. ¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ve al menú `Window` > `CustomizePerspective` > `Menu Visibility` Selecciona > `Run` y selecciona ok!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

He buscado con la ayuda que me proporciono Jorgesys (gracias) y la respuesta está activando esta opcion en el apartado Window > CustomizePerspective > Action Set Aviavility.
https://gyazo.com/830c520a23b724b2bea9cbb5fd8cc52f
Gracias